# Осталось (или остались) четыре вопроса?

Tags: согласование, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно: *остал**ось** четыре вопроса* или *остал**ись** четыре вопроса*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если о самих вопросах ничего не говорится и смысл суждения — в их количестве, то естественнее безличная форма (вопросов осталось столько-то).
Второе может понадобиться в контексте, когда об этих вопросах что-то уточняется, например: *четыре интересных вопроса остались без ответа.*
Аналогично: предпочтительно "остались" (хотя возможны оба варианта) в случае, если сразу за этим перечисляется, ***что*** это за вопросы.
Здесь нет резкой границы между "правильно" и "неправильно", но для хорошего стиля важно учитывать контекст.